# The best way to organize my code for a javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture

Oh hi,
I saw some interesting posts about this subject but I think it's a really personal question that needs a customized answer. So I'm asking you what is the best way to organize my code for a Javascript plugin that need to be the more unobstructiv posible.

So my code looks like that :

```
    var myApp = (function(){
        //here are my global methods or variables
        var self = this;
        return {
            method1:function(){}
            method2:function(){}
            method3:function(){}
    }

   })() || (myApp = {})
myApp.method1();
```

I execute the method1 that calls or use the entire code of my app.
I think i could add and onload event with addEventListener method to execute this method1, and i guess my code could have a better organisation.
I want to precise that my plugin is a bit small, like 200 lanes of javascript code, and it must be in Vanilla js. It's used on a single page in a website, no need to do a prototype class called with "new", in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your project and what you're trying to obtain. 
There are several patterns that help you organize and maintain your code better.
I for one use a combination of patterns that I've made myself comfortable with among the years.
Here's my boilerplate for a *module* of my application :

```
;(function(global, udnefined){

    var app = global.app || {},
        moduleName = 'util',
        module = app[moduleName] || {};

    // "private" vars
    var version = "1.2";

    // fake "private" members (the udnerscore naming convention)
    module._bindEventHandlers = function(){
        // code here

        // for chainability purposes
        return this;
    }

    // "public" method
    module.someMethod = function(){


        // for chainability purposes
        return this;
    }

    // "public" method
    module.someOtherMethod = function(){


        // for chainability purposes
        return this;
    }

    // the init method
    module.init = function(){
        this
            ._bindEventHandlers()
            .someMethod();
    }

    app[moduleName] = module;
    global.app = app;

})(this);
```

And then, in your app (in the app initialization or whenever you actually need the module) you can simply call :

```
app.util.init();
app.util.someOtherMethod();
```

The provided *module* is highly reusable for creating new modules, because most modules should have an initialization logic (the `init` method), most of them would listen to some events (be it dom or custom events) - the `_bindEventHandlers` method - and it doesn't pollute the global namespace with variables (it just adds an object to the main app).

Answer (score 1):

i use somthing the lines of this. all depenting on what i need to get done

```
(function(app, undefined){ 
  var module = app.module = (function(){
    var privatestuff

    return {}
  }())

  var singelton = app.singleton = (function(){
    var Module = function(){}

    module.prototype.method1 = function(){}

    return new Module()
  }())

  var ModulePrototype = app.ModulePrototype = function(){
    var Module = function(){}

    module.prototype.method1 = function(){}

    return Module
  }
}(myApp = window.myApp ||{}))
```